# Getting Error: Unknown system call 20. Assembly Code

Tags: assembly, mips

This is a program in MIPS assembly run through QTSpim which takes the given numbers in a quadratic function and displays the parabola.  This is one of my first low-level programs and im not a good programmer in any form.
So when I run the program it says Unknown system call: 20.  Which is the number I am entering for the upper bound of the range.  The numbers i have been using to test are 1,-1,-6 for the coefficients, -10,10 for the x axis, and -10,20 for the y.  It should display a parabola however it is only displaying the X and Y axis.  This is a step forward however because yesterday it wouldnt display anything. HELP!

```
.text
.globl main
main:
    la $a0,prompt1           # display "Enter the coeficiants of the quadratic: "
    li $v0,4
    syscall

    li $v0,5                 # enter A -> v0
    syscall
    move $t0,$v0             # t0 <--- v0

    li $v0,5                 # enter B -> v0
    syscall
    move $t1,$v0             # t1 <--- v0

    li $v0, 5                # enter C -> v0
    syscall
    move $t2,$v0             # t2 <--- v0

    la $a0,prompt2           # display "Enter the lower (first) and upper (second) bounds of the domain: "
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    li $v0, 5                # enter lower bound -> v0
    syscall
    move $t3, $v0            # t3 <--- v0

    li $v0, 5                # enter upper bound -> v0
    syscall
    move $t4, $v0            # t4 <--- v0

    la $a0, prompt3          # display "Enter the lower (first) and upper (second) bounds of the range: "
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    li $v0, 5                # enter lower bound -> v0
    syscall
    move $t6, $v0            # t6 <--- v0

    li $v0, 5                # enter upper bound -> v0
    syscall
    move $t7, $v0            # t7 <--- v0

    move $t8, $t7            # t8 <--- t7
    syscall

step10: move $t9, $t3            # t9 <--- t3
    syscall

step11: mul $t5,$t3,$t0          # t0 * t3 -> t5
    add $t5,$t1,$t5          # t5 + t1 -> t5
    mul $t5,$t5,$t3          # t5 * t3 -> t5
    add $t5,$t5,$t2          # t5 + t2 -> t5

    beq $t8, $t5, point      # if y = f(x) goto point marker

    beqz $t9, yaxis          # if x = 0 goto yaxis

    beqz $t8, xaxis          # if y = 0 goto xaxis

    la $a0,space             # display " "
    li $v0,4
    syscall

step16: beq $t9, $t4, newl       # if x = x-max goto newl

    add $t9, $t9, 1          # $t9 += 1

    j step11

step18: beq $t8, $t6, EOP        # if y = y-min end program

    sub $t8, $t8, 1          # $t8 -= 1

    j step10

EOP:    li $v0,10                # EOP
    syscall

newl:   la $a0,endl              # display "\n"
    li $v0,4
    syscall        
    j step18

point:  la $a0,star              # display "*"
    li $v0,4
    syscall
    j step16

yaxis:  la $a0,bar               # display "|"
    li $v0,4
    syscall
    j step16

xaxis:  la $a0,hyph              # display "-"
    li $v0,4
    syscall
    j step16


    .data
prompt1: .asciiz "Enter the coeficiants of the quadratic: "
prompt2: .asciiz "Enter the lower (first) and upper (second) bounds of the domain: "
prompt3: .asciiz "Enter the lower (first) and upper (second) bounds of the range: "
bar:     .asciiz "|"
star:    .asciiz "*"
hyph:    .asciiz "-"
space:   .asciiz " "
endl:    .asciiz "\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

So, while you're reading input, you use the return value of one system-call as the call-number for the next:

```
[...]
    li $v0, 5                # enter upper bound -> v0
    syscall
    move $t7, $v0            # t7 <--- v0

    move $t8, $t7            # t8 <--- t7
    syscall                  #$v0 is still whatever user input for upper bound

step10: move $t9, $t3        # t9 <--- t3
    syscall                  #$v0 is whatever the last (unspecified) syscall returned
```

I don't know what `syscall`s you *want* to call, so I can't help you there. I recommend writing the code in a higher-level language before writing assembly.

MARS/SPIM system-calls are documented in https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html - decide which one you want, and put its call number in `$v0`, and its incoming args in the registers specified by the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, Im not sure why i wrote syscall there but it stopped my error.  However, logically, it is still only displaying the x and y axis, while not displaying the points

Comment: I'm not going to dig through your program logic unassisted, for free. You presumably have some algorithm/pseudo-code/design document/high-level language code that you've implemented in assembly. If you don't, there's your problem. If you do, **post it**, so others can understand what the program is *supposed* to do.